# Кроссбраузерный blur элементов на странице

Tags: filter, svg, html, css, blur

На одном из проектов возникла задача - необходимо реализиовать смазывание картинок и элементов страницы. При этом нужна поддержка **IE8+**.

Для модных браузеров вопрос решил с `filter: blur(...)`.

Также можно сделать более-менее адекватный blur на базе SVG, там где нет поддержки фильтров.

Но возникает следующая проблема - если нужно смазать картинки, то SVG фильтр срабатывает, а если другие элементы страницы (обычный `div` к примеру), то здесь отдыхает даже IE 11.

Нашел [плагин для jQuery](http://nbartlomiej.github.io/foggy/), но он дает не тот результат, который нужен. (Больше похоже на то что элемент раздавили, нежели смазали)

Сталкивался ли кто-нибудь с подобной задачей? Может есть решение?

Comment: @Павел Азанов, костыли для CSS3 не помогают?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Павел Азанов, для осла 9-й и, возможно, 8-й версий можно тоже использовать [filter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms532979%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(pixelRadius=2);
```

[Тестим в IE](http://jsfiddle.net/odw5rab0/). С 11-м - печалька. Есть еще пара плагинов: [CSS-Filters-Polyfill](https://github.com/Schepp/CSS-Filters-Polyfill) и [Blur.js](https://github.com/jakiestfu/Blur.js) для IE 9+. Попробуйте их, может, чего выйдет.

Comment: @Deonis: Спасибо, с фильтром решилась проблема с IE 8 и 9. Начиная с 10 версии поддержку DirectX фильтров убрали судя по информации [здесь](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-us/library/ie/ms532979(v=vs.85).aspx). За ссылки на плагины спасибо, но они не решают вопрос с IE 10 и выше. Похоже что придется поставить просто заглушку.

Comment: Решаю ту же проблему) а что значить "придется поставить просто заглушку"? откажитесь от применения,в некоторых браузерах?

Comment: @Fikret Да, просто отказаться и сделать, например, полупрозрачный фон, либо показывать заранее подготовленный смазанный скриншот страницы. Для IE10-11 кстати есть решение - отрисовка страницы в canvas и последующий blur. Но не советую, работает медленно.

Comment: @Alex78191, ответы - в ответы, а не в правки. И полезность ссылки на msdn тоже сомнительна.

Comment: @Qwertiy задай вопрос на мете: почему vikttur, и AGS17 приняли правку со сслкой на msdn. по-моему она полезна, что описаны дополнительные пттрибуты.

Comment: @Alex78191, что тебе мешает написать отдельный ответ?

Comment: @Alex78191 SVG фильтр в IE будет работать только с картинками (о чем и было сказано в вопросе). Проблема была в применении фильтра к другим элементам на странице.