# MS EDGE, MS IE не понимает размытие filter: blur

Tags: css, internet-explorer, blur

Как мне им дать понять что блок нужно мылить? Или никак? Только канвас?

Забыл сказать, нужно чтобы background был с center fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Вот метод грубого размытия, который работает во всех браузерах (включая IE 10/11) и не требует фильтров, canvas или JavaScript.

Основная техника должна сократить размер изображения, затем использовать 3D измеряющую матрицу на родителе, чтобы изменить масштаб изображения назад к полному размеру. Это эффективно снижает разрешение изображение и делает грубый эффект размывания.

```css
body {
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.container {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#image {
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/HoWL6o3.jpg');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

#image.blur {
  transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0,
                      0, 1, 0, 0,
                      0, 0, 1, 0,
                      0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  background-size: 0 0;
}

#image.blur:before {
  transform: scale(0.05);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  content: '';  
  background-image: inherit;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="image" class="blur"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Метод размытия на cancas для IE 9+**

https://jsfiddle.net/27tc5L5z/1/ - Смотреть тут, так как картинка должна быть доступна по CORS.

```js
function detectIE() {
  return navigator.userAgent.search(/MSIE|Trident|Edge/) >= 0;
}

let image = document.querySelector('#img-for-blur');
image.src = image.getAttribute('data-src');
if (detectIE()) {
  image.onload = function() {
    StackBlur.image('img-for-blur', 'ie-canvas', 4, false);
  };
} else {
  image.style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
img {
  filter: blur(4px);
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/stackblur-canvas/1.4.0/stackblur.js"></script>
<img id="img-for-blur" data-src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/oURrw.png">
<canvas id="ie-canvas"></canvas>
```

1) Используйте уже упомянутый CSS, чтобы он работал на браузерах без IE без накладных расходов на использования canvas размытия для IE с помощью либы, которое описано ниже:

```
    filter: blur(1px);
```

2) Определите, используется ли Internet Explorer / Microsoft Edge с помощью [этого JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19999388/check-if-user-is-using-ie-with-jquery#21712356).

```js
/**
 * detect IE
 * returns version of IE or false, if browser is not Internet Explorer
 */
function detectIE() {
    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;

    var msie = ua.indexOf('MSIE ');
    if (msie > 0) {
        // IE 10 or older => return version number
        return parseInt(ua.substring(msie + 5, ua.indexOf('.', msie)), 10);
    }

    var trident = ua.indexOf('Trident/');
    if (trident > 0) {
        // IE 11 => return version number
        var rv = ua.indexOf('rv:');
        return parseInt(ua.substring(rv + 3, ua.indexOf('.', rv)), 10);
    }

    var edge = ua.indexOf('Edge/');
    if (edge > 0) {
       // Edge (IE 12+) => return version number
       return parseInt(ua.substring(edge + 5, ua.indexOf('.', edge)), 10);
    }

    // other browser
    return false;
}
```

3) Если обнаружен Internet Explorer / Microsoft Edge, загрузите изображение в скрытое поле «img» на странице. Вы должны сделать это, используя функцию «onload», чтобы [убедиться, что изображение загружено](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342132/waiting-for-image-to-load-in-javascript#2342181), прежде чем работать с ним, иначе следующий шаг не удастся:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() { blurTheImage(); }
img.src = "http://path/to/image.jpg";
```

4) Используйте JavaScript библиотеку [StackBlur](http://quasimondo.com/StackBlurForCanvas/StackBlurDemo.html), которая работает на IE и Edge:

HTML:

```
    <div id="ie-image-area" style="display: none;">
        <img id="ie-image"/>
        <canvas id="ie-canvas"></canvas>
    </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function blurTheImage() {
    $("#ie-image").attr("src", "http://path/to/image.jpg");
    StackBlur.image('ie-image', 'ie-canvas', 1, false);
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/412624/blur-%D1%8D%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-jquery?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Ещё для себя открыл пример.

1. Фон (bg.jpg).
2. Размытый дубликат фона (bgblur.jpg).

Есть допустим body, и мой несчастный блок.

HTML:

```
<div class="blurred">TEXT</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background: url('bg.jpg') no-repeat no-repeat center fixed;
}
.blurred {
    background: url('bgblur.jpg') no-repeat no-repeat center fixed;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Тем самым я замылил блок как мне нужно, но есть минус, 2 фона. Ну ничего.

Answer (score 0):

Фильтр размытия SVG, применяемый к элементу изображения SVG **IE 10+**
http://jsfiddle.net/jamygolden/yUG5U/2/ (при наведении)
Для более старых (<= IE 9) [можно использовать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/355960/182273)

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(pixelRadius=2);
```

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms532979%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```css
#svg-image-blur {
  height: 220px;
  width: 320px;
  filter: url(#blur-effect-1);
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg-image-blur">
    <image id="svg-image"xlink:href="http://css-plus.com/examples/2012/03/gaussian-blur/i/fence.jpg" />

    <filter id="blur-effect-1">
        <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2" />
    </filter>
</svg>
```